# mysql-connector-python query with WHERE IN

Tags: python, mysql-connector-python

I am trying to query a table with WHERE IN condition using mysql-connector-python like this:

```
ids = (12, 31)
cursor.execute("SELECT object_name FROM object_table WHERE object_id IN %s", ids)
```

And I get the following error:

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement
```

How can I get it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add "" in ids to be a String and also ',' should be replaced with '%'

E.g.

```
ids = "(12, 31)"
cursor.execute("SELECT object_name FROM object_table WHERE object_id IN %s" % ids)
```

Answer (score 0):

A query should be in the string format so you need to wrap your variable `ids = (12, 31)` into a string like `ids = "(12, 31)"` and
also don't forget the add `%` instead of `,` as you're passing some value.

```
ids = "(12, 31)"
cursor.execute("SELECT object_name FROM object_table WHERE object_id IN %s" % ids)
```

Answer (score 0):

old answer but might be helpful for someone

this is what I did and it might be helpful here if ids is a list.

```
query = "UPDATE tableName SET lspaasStatus = 1 WHERE CompletedQuizId IN " + "("+str(updatedQuizids)[1:-1]+")"
mycursor.execute(query)
```